# Can't set language mode for ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I can set language modes for javascript, css, html, json by this construction:

```
var JavaScriptMode = require("ace/mode/javascript").Mode;
editor.getSession().setMode(new JavaScriptMode());
```

But I can't set language modes for ruby, java and maybe for another languages.

In my project I have a folder with ace's files like these:

```
mode-javascript.js
mode-html.js
mode-css.js
mode-json.js
mode-java.js
mode-ruby.js
...
```

I assume that these files used to set language mode but why it possible for some languages but not for another languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It requires to connect javascript library in html page:

```
<script src="js/ace-0.2.0/src/mode-ruby.js"></script>
```